# Can you change the opacity of a white image without getting a gray result?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency

I'm sort of hacking the interface of Wunderlist (To-do app) and originally all tasks backgrounds are 0% transparant, slightly gray coloured. I'm trying to change the opacity of each. Luckily, Wunderlist uses images for their UI.

[image]

However, when I change the opacity of the image and copy it to the resources folder of the app, it's gray in the app..

[image: Screenshot]
- The result after my edits

[image: The original UI]
Originally, the task bars look all as white, slightly gray as in the original image above

I'm currently looking for a way to have white, slightly (60%) opaque bars instead of the gray ones in the screenshot above. If possible, even whiter than in the second (original) image.

I've tried simply changing the transparant layer value and also messing with the channels, but all result in the gray bars as below.

Who got some suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the file that you are inserting? I suspect that it might simply not be white.

Comment: @KMSTR, The file with the text "Link to the original image" is a link to the original file. It indeed is not 100% white, slightly gray, just as you can see in the second image I've attached. However! A flat, perfect white but 60% opaque image with W.192px X H.68px dimensions would perfectly fit as an answer. However, I'd still like to know how to achieve transparency, but keep the perfect white color. Thanks!

Comment: Then I don't understand the question. Do you want it to be gray like the first or whit as the second?

Comment: I'll change the topic itself right after this comment.. The second image is how Wunderlist itself is, originally. The first image is after I edited the source images, where you can see the bars became transparent, but gray. What I would like to achieve is to have those bars be equal or even whiter as the white bars in the second image, but half less opaque, so they become see-through. 
To achieve that, I need a 192x68px flat white coloured, 50% transparent image. I hope that clarifies enough? Thanks!

Comment: I honestly think the problem lies in the app itself, instead of the image. Call me wrong, but i'd say the most brightest white image with 50% transparency, is one where in Photoshop I create a white filled layer and adjust the fill to 50% and then save as PNG. - Just like that I did, but it remains quite gray, just like in the first image I've attached..

Comment: Probably, you want to see the underlying layer through the white bars? If so, your question is about blending modes.

Comment: @Ilan, that's correct. However, it's a single layer file (at least, now). How do blending modes work then? The bar is an image on top of the whole application itself.

Comment: @SanderSchaeffer what app do you use to edit the original app and build the file/project?

Comment: I use Photoshop to edit the image that I had a link to. Within my Mac, app folder, I just right-click the app and choose 'show package contents' and replace the original source image. I don't work with code at any time to make these changes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac Applications are normally build using [xCode](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12).

When we place an image into application, within xCode we can choose how we want this image to be shown: for example if we want some image disappear slowly, we rise its transparency by operating (decreasing) Alpha -

[image]

If we change the Alpha and built the application, then the Application will change the original picture accordingly to the alpha value in the build time.

Thus, if you exchange the picture in folder and not change the alpha within xCode before building the Application, expectably you will get unexpected results.

If the explanation above is related to your situation, you only can play with the parameters and try to achieve the result you want. If you want expected results, you should have the xCode source file which is impossible in your situation.

Comment: Thanks for your extended answer. With every comment more I was getting more and more sure and afraid that the expected result I'd want to achieve was not achievable. The application is indeed written in xCode, but sadly I do not have the source files, only the application itself. I've tried my best by exchanging the images within the application, without editing the app itself. I think I have to live with the results I got till now. Thank you.